# Angular browser back button doesn't work properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router, back-button

When browser back button clicked the app redirects to the first url of the app. For example, current route is `localhost:3000` then I'm going to home `localhost:3000/home` and then to `localhost:3000/settings` and when I click on browser back button it redirects me to `localhost:3000` instead of `localhost:3000/home`.

I'm using angular 14, but when I started building the app angular was of version 13.
This is `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        ...
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This is `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, onSameUrlNavigation: "reload" }),
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

The routes all look like this:

```
    {
        path: "user/profile",
        loadChildren: () => import("./user/profile/profile.module").then(m => m.ProfilePageModule),
        canActivate: [LoggedGuard],
    },
```

This is the navigation function that used everywhere for navigation:

```
async go(path: string[], options: NavigationExtras = {}, showLoader: boolean = true) {
    if(showLoader === true) {
      await this.loader.start();
    }
    this.router.navigate(path, { replaceUrl: true, ...options});
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured it out. The function `go()` in the question has `replaceUrl: true` which **replaces the url and not saving the url to browser's history**, which means that if you click browser back button it work as you want it to work. Set `replaceUrl: false` to save the url to browser history and browser back button will work properly.

So this is how the function looks now:

```
async go(path: string[], options: NavigationExtras = {}, showLoader: boolean = true) {
    if(showLoader === true) {
      await this.loader.start();
    }
    this.router.navigate(path, { replaceUrl: false, ...options});
  }
```

Another thing, please try to use `<a routerLink="path"></a>` when possible. This way when the user clicks on link with mouse middle button(scroll wheel) the page will be opened in new tab. Buttons doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you share a stackblitz project reproducing your problem.

Maybe it's a problem related with the definition of the routes. You need to set the  route to default page, in your case is *home*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then( m => m.ProfilePageModule)
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks, Antonio for contribution. I have just figured it out. router.navigate() with replaceUrl:true just replaces the url and the url is not saved in browser's history because it just replaces the url. Set replaceUrl:false to save the url to browser history, then browser back button works as it is supposed to. Also try to use <a> with [routerLink] when possible.